# Can't call iterator() method of my object

Tags: java, iterator

I am learning to use the Iterator Interface, but I'm stuck because Eclipse shows "Cannot resolve to a type" when I call the iterator() method of my LinkedList A with A.iterator() in the code block just below. I searched, but I don't find why this happens, and how I can call A.iterator(). This is the code where I try to call the A.iterator()-method:

```
import abstractDataTypes.LinkedList.*;

public class LinkedListIteratorTest {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> A = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        A.insert(1);
        A.insert(3);
        A.insert(1);
        A.insert(7);
        A.insert(6);
        ListIterator li = new A.iterator();
        for(;li.hasNext();) {
            System.out.println(li.next());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the part of the code in my LinkedList-class, where interator() is defined:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class LinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    ListNode<T> head;
    ListNode<T> tail;

    public LinkedList() {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new ListIterator<T>(head);
    }
...
```

ListIterator() is defined as a class inside the LinkedList-class:

```
    ...
    class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
        ListNode<T> current;
        ListIterator(ListNode<T> head) {
            current = head;
        }
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (current != null);
        }
   ...
```

Comment: Post the exact and complete error message, and tell us which line it refers to.

Comment: Remove the `new` in `ListIterator li = new A.iterator();`. You are not instantiating an object but getting an existing one.

Comment: YESS thanks deleting "new" was right! How can I Close this question?

Comment: @Tunaki This should be an answer =) @m b You can't, question stay open for further consultation by others users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tunaki answered the question:

Remove the `new` in `ListIterator li = new A.iterator();`.